# Не выполняется действие

Tags: javascript, html

Не выполняется *расчёт средней зарплаты*.

Если писать так

```js
let table = document.getElementById('empls');
let row = table.insertRow(-1);
```

то всё работает правильно, но добавляет не туда

Нужно чтобы добавлял в `thead`

```js
const statistics = [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0]
];

const categories = [
    'Молодой возраст',
    'Средний возраст',
    'Старший возраст'
];

const addEmployee=()=>{
    let info = document.getElementsByName('info');
    
    let fio    = info[0].value;
    let date   = info[1].value;
    let salary = info[2].value;
    
    let table = document.getElementById('empls').getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
    
    let row = table.insertRow(-1);
    
    let age      = getAge(date);
    let category = getCategory(age);
    
    statistics[category][0]++;
    statistics[category][1] += (salary - 0);
    
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = fio;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = date;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = salary;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = age;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = categories[category];
    
    table.rows[categories[category]].cells[1].innerHTML = statistics[category][1] / statistics[category][0];
};

const getAge=(date)=>{
    return (new Date().getFullYear() - new Date(date).getFullYear());
};

const getCategory=(age)=>{
    let res = -1;
    
    if(age < 30){
        res = 0;
    }else if(age <= 55){
        res = 1;
    }else{
        res = 2;
    }
    
    return res;
};
```

```html
<div class="row content-div">
    <div class="row">
        <p>
            ФИО
            <input type="text" name="info" value="">
        </p>
        <p>
            Дата рождения
            <input type="date" name="info" value="1990-01-01">
        </p>
        <p>
            Оклад
            <input type="number" name="info" value="">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" name="" value="Отправить" onclick="addEmployee()">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table border="1" width="100%" id="empls">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ФИО</th>
                    <th>Дата рождения</th>
                    <th>Оклад</th>
                    <th>Возраст</th>
                    <th>Категория</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="Молодой возраст">
                    <td colspan=4>Средняя зарплата "молодых" работников:</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Средний возраст">
                    <td colspan=4>Средняя зарплата "средних" работников:</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Старший возраст">
                    <td colspan=4>Средняя зарплата "старших" работников:</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я бы смотрел в строну jquery для уменьшения человекочасов(чем програмизды и занимаются кста) + когда создаешь функцию (через пелеменную), семиколон не забывай ставить, а так уже можешь про es6 идти читать

Comment: @Vadim, при правке вопросов по коду, не надо править сам код, это может привести как к решению ошибки, и в этом случае никто не узнает в чем была ошибка, так и к созданию новых ошибок, и в этом случае будут решены твои ошибки, а не исходные ошибки автора вопроса.